# How to interpret these two graphs showing Rsquared and RMSE values?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, predictive-models, interpretation

I built some predictive model to predict the citation count of papers published on different journal. I was comparing the goodness of fit via $R^2$ and $RMSE$. Here are the graphs that I am talking about.
[[image: <span class=]$R^2$ results" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpPFO.png)

[[image: <span class=]$RMSE$ results" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Uj0.png)

I am not sure how to interpret the results of these two graphs as to my understanding they do not agree. For example arXiv according to $R^2$ is the second easiest to predict and according to $RMSE$ is the hardest among all to predict. Can someone help me understand why is this happening, or maybe help me understand that this is not a weird outcome? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$R^2$ is $1 - \operatorname{MSE}(y, \hat y) / \operatorname{Var}(y)$ and RMSE is $\sqrt{\operatorname{MSE}(y, \hat y)}$, so they measure same thing, but the first one is normalized by variance. It seems like those sources differ in variances of the citation counts. Since all the predicted quantities use the same measurement units (counts of citations), RMSE is probably easier to interpret.